# Firebug memory usage

Tags: firefox, memory-leaks, firebug

Is Firebug a bit of a memory hog when you run it for a while? Or is it just Firefox? I kinda get to the point where my firefox is using 1 Gb of memory and everything just slows down.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

**EDIT** I am running the latest and greatest versions of both.

**EDIT** I suppose there is no real answer to this, but it would be good if people share their tips and tricks on reducing the imapact of growing memory footprint. Community wiki now.

Comment: What version of each are you running?

Comment: I think this belongs to superuser.

Comment: Firebug is a development tool, so I think it's appropriate to ask a question about it here.

Comment: Your problem is not with developing anything but just a normal problem happening to you as a computer user.

Comment: That's a bit like saying any questions about Visual Studio should be on superuser. Firebug is used in 99% of the cases as a development tool. I don't see a problem with it being here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is well know by its memory usage 
but there are some tips and tricks you can do it to make it work faster

I think this [POST](http://www.dagho.com/wp/improving-the-speed-of-firefox-3/2009/10/19/) will help you ,
and there are an [ADDON CALLED  FASTERFOX](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1269) (Note : its compatiable with firefox 2 only but you can find another trick to do it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQADaqGZOKE)
that is all I Knew

Comment: Finally got around to setting all the values. Will see how it goes with prolonged firebug usage. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Seems a lot snappier, looks like it's as good as it gets. I think this is as much of an answer as I'd ever get.

Comment: you can check this site if you would to follow up with more hacks http://hacks.mozilla.org

Answer (score 2):

It's Firefox and [it's a feature](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/ben/archives/009749.html).